# SetWindowsHookEx hook stops working

Tags: c#, winapi, keyboard, unmanaged

## Keyboard hook not firing events and throws win32 exception on dispose

My c# application creates keyboard hook for processing of keyboard events(many card readers, scanners and other POS equipment emulates keyboard).
Sometimes my application creates keyboard hook without errors, but it's not firings events and on dispose throws exception:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Failed to remove keyboard hooks for 'app'. Error 1404: Invalid hook handle

Other log entry is same error, but it tells about

> ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED

[Source code of library and demo app.](https://github.com/Dedrus/keyboardhook)

I can't reproduce this problem on my pc, and don't know what I should investigate or google.
I know that:

- All clients with this strange behaviour using x86 operating system.
- There can be some problems with windows privilegies or rights.
- It breaks sometimes(not always).
- Library targets .NET 4
- Application targets .NET 4.5.1
- Compile platform: Any CPU

Also, I'm not fluent with unmanaged code and win api. I got this code from some thread and modified it for my needs but on high level of abstraction.

Hook ctor:

```
public GlobalKeyboardHook()
{
    _windowsHookHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
    _user32LibraryHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
    _hookProc = LowLevelKeyboardProc; // we must keep alive _hookProc, because GC is not aware about SetWindowsHookEx behaviour.

    _user32LibraryHandle = LoadLibrary("User32");
    if (_user32LibraryHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        throw new Win32Exception(errorCode,
            $"Failed to load library 'User32.dll'. Error {errorCode}: {new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message}.");
    }


    _windowsHookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, _hookProc, _user32LibraryHandle, 0);
    if (_windowsHookHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        throw new Win32Exception(errorCode,
            $"Failed to adjust keyboard hooks for '{Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName}'. Error {errorCode}: {new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message}.");
    }
}
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
[DllImport("USER32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, int dwThreadId);
```

Hook dispose:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        // because we can unhook only in the same thread, not in garbage collector thread
        if (_windowsHookHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            if (!UnhookWindowsHookEx(_windowsHookHandle))
            {
                int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new Win32Exception(errorCode,
                    $"Failed to remove keyboard hooks for '{Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName}'. Error {errorCode}: {new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message}.");
            }
            _windowsHookHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

            // ReSharper disable once DelegateSubtraction
            _hookProc -= LowLevelKeyboardProc;
        }
    }

    if (_user32LibraryHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        if (!FreeLibrary(_user32LibraryHandle)) // reduces reference to library by 1.
        {
            int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            throw new Win32Exception(errorCode,
                $"Failed to unload library 'User32.dll'. Error {errorCode}: {new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message}.");
        }
        _user32LibraryHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

[DllImport("USER32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hHook);
```

Comment: Pretty sure you should be calling `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, _hookProc, IntPtr.Zero, GetCurrentThreadId ());`  i.e. don't pass a value for _module_

Comment: @MickyD No, LL hooks are global only.

Comment: If a .NET application installed a global hook on my system it would get uninstalled immediately.

Comment: The LoadLibrary() and FreeLibrary() declarations are wrong, they are missing SetLastError = true.  There is no protection in the code against accidentally calling SetWindowsHookEx() twice.  This will end poorly with a random crash when the garbage collector runs and a 1404 error.  ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED is a security error code, indicating the user account does not have enough privileges.   That's about all I can see.

Comment: @Anders yes of course.  Thanks

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, I will add this. But if user does not have enough privilegies my program should not work at all, isn't it?

Comment: I'm also will try to resolve my problem by using [this library](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do something wrong in the hook proc Windows will unhook you without telling you.

- In your `LowLevelKeyboardProc` you are not checking `nCode`! You must do that first and if `nCode` is < 0 you **must** return with `CallNextHookEx` without any other processing.
- You cannot spend too much time inside the hook proc. The exact limit is not documented AFAIK **and** can be changed by a registry value. You should aim for < 200ms to be safe.

You could try setting/changing the `LowLevelHooksTimeout` registry value on the problematic systems to see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I will investigate it. If I will add Thread.Sleep in callback can I reproduce this on my PC?

Comment: As I understand LowLevelHooksTimeout exists only on windows 7 systems? All clients with this problem are running windows 7. I've found [this article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/f6032ca1-31b8-4ad5-be39-f78dd29952da/hooking-problem-in-windows-7?forum=windowscompatibility)

Comment: I'm guessing it is Windows 7 and newer. All systems have a timeout (you can't block/ignore a key after timeout because it ignores your return value) but only 7+ will unhook you (IIRC).

Comment: Man, You saved my life. I reproduced this behaviour on my pc after adding Thread.Sleep(2000) in callback on my windows 10!

Comment: If you never actually need to eat/abort a keystroke you might want to implement the hook proc as a simple call to PostMessage that posts a message to one of your windows on another thread.