# DLL injected with SetWindowsHookEx is being unloaded unexpectedly

Tags: windows, hook, setwindowshookex

My program calls `SetWindowsHookEx` to inject my DLL into a single target process.  My DLL contains both a `WH_GETMESSAGE` and a `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook:

```
hGetMessageProcHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE,
        MyGetMsgProc,
        hMyDLLModule,
        dwTargetThreadId);

hCallWndProcHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC,
        MyCallWndProc,
        hMyDLLModule,
        dwTargetThreadId);
```

I never call `UnhookWindowsHookEx`.  Windows unloads my DLL automatically, after my program terminates (cleanly or not), when the target app next pumps a Windows message.  Both hooks are working well.

But on one machine running Windows Server 2016, *Process Explorer* shows that my DLL sometimes is unloaded without warning, of course my hook doesn't function any more.  I have never seen this before.  Is this some protection in Windows Server?

Comment: Hooks affect the overall system performance. That's why the system requires hooks to cooperate, e.g. by mandating that they retire in a timely fashion. If a hook procedure fails to do this, the system does what it needs to do to establish system stability. I don't know whether unloading modules is part of this, though removing a hook certainly is.

Comment: @IInspectable that can’t be right. There is nothing that says a hook needs to be short running.

Comment: If that can't be it, then most likely the system just hates you, personally. Not sure how to approach that.

Comment: @IInspectable After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48696616/2073217) I see what you are saying.  I thought you were saying the hook could only be set/installed into the system for a short time, not that it had to execute within a short time.